# Android Studio 2.2.3 のプロジェクトペインの表示について

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studioでjavaを使いAndroidアプリ開発を学び始めました。

教科書(本気で学ぶAndroidアプリ開発入門 第2版)にはプロジェクトペイン上部に現在表示しているファイルのある場所に移動するボタンが設定ボタン(歯車)の左側にあると書いているのですが、
そのようなボタンが見当たりません
どこかの表示設定で出すことはできないでしょうか？
また、現在表示しているファイルの場所に移動するショートカットキーなどありますでしょうか？

ごく基本的な質問で申し訳ありません
どなたかよろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 実際の表示画面]

Comment: 探しているのは"Scroll from Source"という名前の機能ではないかと思います。
/ 質問タイトルに記載されているバージョンについてですが、[現在の最新安定版の2.2.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)の誤記か、あるいは
[2.3beta3](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary)のことだと思うのですが、正確に記載した方が良いかと考えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます修正いたしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく日本語化したことが原因なので、もとに戻せば解決すると思います。

http://s3wordpress.wpblog.jp/2016/05/18/android-studio-2-0-%E3%82%92%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E5%8C%96%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F/

の手順を試してみたところ再現しました。

Comment: 日本語化を切ったところ、表示されました。ありがとうございます
でもこれ日本語化したままでは無理ですよね…
何とか英語のままでやってみます

本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

Pleiades で日本語化した場合は問題なくアイコンが表示されます。
http://qiita.com/cypher256/items/a87179fbe8dd7f63ec4e